# Regex match everything before n-th occurrence

Tags: regex

I have a regex  pattern to use on working directory paths. The objective attempt is to grab everything before four forward slashes. Therefore, never exceed capturing string values after four forward slashes.

I have attempted two approaches:

```
[^\\].*[\\]
```

Which grabs all values up to a forward slash , for example:

```
C:\Users\testing\again\later

#I will grab
C:\Users\testing\again\
```

However, if there is a leading forward slash, this will capture it, regardless if it occurs four times or not. I have also attempted:

```
(?=[\\]){4}.*[\\]
```

However, this again will grab for any number of leading forward slashes.

Comment: Note: Those are back-slashes, not forward-slashes :)

Comment: Just use `^(?:[^\\]*\\){4}`

Comment: are you trying to just grab `C:` (everything before 4 slashes or everything before the fourth slash (`C:\Users\testing\again`)?

Comment: Is this a coding question, or text editor question? If it's code, then what's the language? If it's the text editor, then which one? Regex syntax is different between editors, and also between coding languages.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?:[^\\]*\\){4}
```

Will grab everything up to the 4th slash.

`^` - Matches start of line
`(?:` `)` - Non-capturing group:
    `[^\\]*` - Matches any number (including zero) of characters except backslashes
    `\\` - Matches literal backslash
`{4}` - Repeats non-Capturing group 4 times

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+)(?:\\.*){4}
```

Will grab everything before the four backslashes. In your case `C:`